# Why would a man transfer humans consciousness into a simulation with skeleton bodies

Tags: internal-consistency, virtual-reality

In the far future where a government is seemingly capable of traversing through universes, when people die, their consciousness stored in a simulation for ever, and they live happily there. Then a man somehow manages to use this hyper advanced simulation system to take over 100,000 dead people's consciousness and transfer their consciousness into his own simulation without telling them what their aim is. This simulation system is filled with countless planets; some filled with life and others not, pretty much simulating our universe. And his own simulation is very different. Upon arrival, the people realize that their bodies are skeletons. They don't know they're in a simulation, so they just think they're in afterlife. They don’t need to eat, sleep, drink, or even reproduce and seemingly can’t die. The planet that they're on is somewhat barren, sporting a few plants, trees, and a few animals all scattered around said planet.

Everyone is seemingly in the same city and in the distance, they can see a medium-sized town, in the center of this town is technology that will allow them to mine minerals and precious resources that live inside their planet, and various others that are designed to allow the making of robots and more, with all having the similarity of not having the added purpose for giving sleep, food and water. Sunflowers are one of the living and important plants and only way to get out of this simulation is to collect 1,000 sunflowers.

Now,

•Why would a scientist transfer 100,000 dead consciousnesses into immortal skeleton bodies, near a village filled with various technologies, upon a planet that is somewhat barren?

•What would be the reason behind collecting 1,000 sunflowers to leave?

•Why would he choose "skeletons" as bodies and "sunflowers" as the price?

Comment: You are asking us to speculate about a character's motivation, this is story based (ie. not what we do here). We can help you construct a fictional world, sort out it's rules, but we do not write your story for you. Please see [on-topic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in the [help] for further clarification of what we expect.

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ForTheEvulz

Answer (score 2):

## AI training

Your evil overlord wants to make robots that ruthlessly collect sunflowers. Your evil overlord doesn't know how to program robots to collect sunflowers. Sure, such problems are  easy to solve within the confines of a nice cubical robot testing arena, but not in the real world. (Have fun programming your robot to work a 9-5 job to make money to buy them from the flower store, if that happens to be the optimal way to get sunflowers)

But humans know all about the real world. And there's a pool of human consciousnesses just ripe for the taking. Why not use those as the starting point to train your sunflower-collecting algorithm?

At the end of the testing period, the 50 humans who collect the most sunflowers will be transferred into real robot bodies. The rest are no longer useful and will be deleted, or archived for future experiments.

Why does your evil overlord want flower-collecting robots? Well, he doesn't, not really. He wants the robots to collect chunks of denucularized macguffium to build his doomsday machine. The robots' camera has a processor which makes denucularized macguffium look like sunflowers which, conveniently, are now extinct on Earth due to the effects of global warming.

Your evil overlord wants to train the robots *before* deploying them, because once they are deployed, the forces of anti-macguffinity will be trying to hunt down and destroy his robots, and he'd like to finish the doomsday machine before then. He trains the robots in a simulation, because the simulation won't alert the anti-macguffinians.

> Why [...] near a village filled with various technologies, upon a planet that is somewhat barren?

The environment mimics the ruins of Earth, where the robots will be deployed.

> What would be the reason behind collecting 1,000 sunflowers to leave?

That's how he finds out which AIs do the best.

> Why would he choose "skeletons" as bodies

Couldn't afford a 3D artist. Skeletons are functional enough.

> and "sunflowers" as the price?

They're not really sunflowers, and the dead people won't complain the way they would if he asked them to collect chunks of radioactive toxic material.