# Benefical Bone Mutations

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency

In the far future where a government is seemingly capable of traversing through universes, when people die, their consciousness stored in a simulation for ever, and they live happily there. Then a man somehow manages to use this hyper advanced simulation system to take over 100,000 dead people's consciousness and transfer their consciousness into his own simulation without telling them what their aim is. This simulation system is filled with countless planets; some filled with life and others not, pretty much simulating our universe. And his own simulation is very different. Upon arrival, the people realize that their bodies are skeletons. They don't know they're in a simulation, so they just think they're in afterlife. They don’t need to eat, sleep, drink, or even reproduce and seemingly can’t die. The planet that they're on is somewhat barren, sporting a few plants, trees, and a few animals all scattered around said planet.

Everyone is seemingly in the same city and in the distance, they can see a medium-sized town, in the center of this town is technology that will allow them to mine minerals and precious resources that live inside their planet, and various others that are designed to allow the making of robots and more, with all having the similarity of not having the added purpose for giving sleep, food and water. Sunflowers are one of the living and important plants and only way to get out of this simulation is to collect 1,000 sunflowers.

In a world like this, which bone mutations would be benefical?
For an example, I think LRP5 Mutation (High bone density) would make the skeleton more difficult to damage so it would be benefical. (By the way, is that true?)

Comment: They're skeletons in a simulation. Just program them however you feel like, it doesn't need to follow science, because you're already not following science.

Comment: What do you mean by "mutations" in the context of a simulation where one hundred thousand skeletonic avatars frolic around sunflowers? The word cannot possibly have its biological meaning.

Comment: Upvote for reasonable writing skills paired with a truly bizarre question.

Comment: They are all irrelevant because they won't transfer over to the [robot bodies](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/169484/why-would-a-man-transfer-humans-consciousness-into-a-simulation-with-skeleton-bo). However, your evil overlord could be testing different types of robot bodies as well as testing the minds.

Answer (score 2):

It's a simulation so you can program it how you want.

That aside, the 'mutations' you are looking for can be greatly differential depending on the use case.  In other words **Form follows function**.

Successful mutations grant some sort of advantage to the organism.  The oversimplified story of the Giraffe ecansulates it nicely. Lots of short necked giraffes are roaming about.  One day, one with a longer neck is able to thrive because he can reach more leaves.  He survives and breeds and his offspring have the same trait.  The savannah gets populated over time, and 3 million years later you have the 16 foot tall critters we see today.  The tall animals can eat leaves of taller trees and feed from branches much higher than other ruminants.  The Form, being 16 ft tall, follows the Function, being able to eat better foliage from higher up a tree.

So for your skeletal mutations, what do the  people in the simulation need to do?  What would give them an advantage.  Extra bone density might be helpful if extra resistance to injury is needed.  If your people need to cover a lot of distance, something like Gigantism without the side effects might be useful, as much longer limbs would help cover more distance quickly.

Diversification of a group working together could come from a number of different mutations.  Extra large hands that could be used as spades, The really tall fast guy, the much shorter guy to get into tight spaces, the 'tank' with extra heavy bones...

Just keep form and function in mind.